# CMake convert date format

Tags: date, cmake, datetime-format

I'm in the process of converting a configure script to a cmake system. HOwever i have run into an apparent brick wall with a particular line:

```
COMMIT_DATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M" -ud "$(LC_ALL=C svn info | grep 'Changed Date' | cut -c20-45)")
```

How can format a date in cmake? Or assuming that i can't, what's the best, cross-platform way to do this? Obviously, this configure script currently only works on linux, however i would like the solution to be as cross-platform as possible.

The svn part can be done relatively easily, so that doesn't need worrying about, other than the date input string is: (e.g.) "2013-10-14 21:55:05 +0100"

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`string`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#timestamp) command, in particular the `TIMESTAMP` version, which allows construction of arbitrary date and time strings.

Note that the timestamp stuff was only introduced with version 2.8.11 of CMake, so if you are stuck with an older version, you might need to resort to third-party tools for obtaining the date.

Comment: That looks nice. However, it seems to only work with current date/time, not an arbitrary one, i think

Comment: @LordAro If you already have an arbitrary date string, you can use string `REGEX` to parse it. It's not as convenient to use as other language's regex but it gets the job done.

Comment: the trouble is with timezones, makes the whole thing much more difficult